# Improving a Remote Wolfram Execution Function

Tags: remote-access

The following function allows me to remotely execute Wolfram code on another machine that has wolframscript installed:

```
Attributes[remoteExecute] = {HoldAllComplete};
remoteExecute[(* remote_, *) expr_] := 
 Module[{compressed, ubuntuBox = RemoteConnect["192.162.0.2", "username", "password"]}, 
  compressed = ExportString[ToString[Hold[expr], InputForm], "Base64"];
  ToExpression[
   RemoteRunProcess[ubuntuBox, 
    "wolframscript -format InputForm -code 'ReleaseHold[ImportString[\
\"" <> compressed <> "\",\"Base64\"]]'", "StandardOutput"]]]
```

For example:

```
(* Return True: *)
FileExistsQ["~/only_on_my_remote_machine"] // remoteExecute
```

**Problem:** This function *doesn't* work on every function, however, and it is mysterious why:

> [image]

How to fix?

Comment: What's returned by the function? If it's a `String` that means the encoding didn't quite go right. By the way this would be easier to write as `Compress[Unevaluated[expr]` and then you would execute by calling `Uncompress[compressed]`. I think you might be happier with that.

Comment: b3m2a1: Is your proposed function then [this](https://gist.github.com/georgewsinger/d71d33a5a272aa5cc12b3fad240eb657) one?

Comment: No. Don't use `ExportString` and don't use `ImportString` or `ReleaseHold`. Just do something like ``RemoteRunProcess[ubuntuBox,  TemplateApply["wolframscript -format InputForm -code 'Uncompress[\"`\`\"]'", Compress[Unevaluated[expr]]]``

Comment: I'm getting compression error output like `Uncompress::corrupt: Compressed data "`Ã¯ÂÂ" is corrupt and does \
not represent an expression.`

Comment: then something is likely going wrong in how you're sending it I figure.

Comment: b3m2a: [Here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/user-900a994f-78ab-4931-b18e-353eff4d0b33/142145885364030469420774281982761786055216266828.png) is the way I'm sending it.

Comment: why did you put backslashes after the ``"\`"``? Two backticks indicate a template in `TemplateApply`.

Comment: b3m2a1: Removing the backslashes worked! Thanks for your help. I think you accidentally included backslashes in your formatted markdown above^.

Comment: Ah right you are. Post a self-answer so people know this has been fixed.

Comment: b3m2a1: There is still an issue where this function doesn't allow me to (i) define custom local functions and then (ii) evaluate those local functions on the remote machine. See [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/user-900a994f-78ab-4931-b18e-353eff4d0b33/775176002484703571574435838273751252102715579122.png) to see what I mean.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: That's a more subtle issue and deserves its own question

Comment: b3m2a1: See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204203/executing-local-functions-remotely) for a new topic on the issue I raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following

```
Attributes[remoteExecute] = {HoldAllComplete};
remoteExecute[expr_] := 
 Module[{compressed, 
   ubuntuBox = RemoteConnect[ip, "username", "password"]}, 
  compressed = Compress[Unevaluated[expr]]; 
  ToExpression[
   RemoteRunProcess[ubuntuBox, 
    TemplateApply[
     "wolframscript -format InputForm -code 'Uncompress[\"``\"]'", 
     compressed], "StandardOutput"]]]
```

is able to execute functions remotely, so long as your function isn't locally defined.