# Executing local functions remotely

Tags: remote-access

The following

```
Attributes[remoteExecute] = {HoldAllComplete};
remoteExecute[expr_] := 
 Module[{compressed, 
   ubuntuBox = RemoteConnect[ip, "username", "password"]}, 
  compressed = Compress[Unevaluated[expr]]; 
  ToExpression[
   RemoteRunProcess[ubuntuBox, 
    TemplateApply[
     "wolframscript -format InputForm -code 'Uncompress[\"``\"]'", 
     compressed], "StandardOutput"]]]
```

is able to execute functions remotely, so long as your function isn't locally defined. So for example if `~/only_on_ubuntu_box` is a file that exists only on your remote machine, this function will fail for:

> [image]

How can one get around this limitation?

Comment: The last statement should return True, since the file is on the remote machine and the local function checks whether a file exists.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Have you considered setting up a remote kernel instead? Those functions automatically find all the local functions needed to execute the function that you want to execute on the remote kernel and send those definitions along.

Comment: Can the remote kernel be set up with wolframscript? I don't have a license on the remote machine.

Comment: If you have `wolframscript` then I assume that you have Wolfram Engine, and I think that Wolfram Engine can be used as a remote kernel even though I haven't tried it.

Comment: It's not very clear from Wolfram documentation (which is unusual; Wolfram documentation is usually excellent) how to do set up a remote kernel over SSH (both machines running Linux) and then forcing commands to execute on the remote kernel.

Comment: I don't have any experience with this, unfortunately, but [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105573/731) and [this package](https://github.com/sakra/Tunnel) seem related.

Comment: Try something like `FileExistsQ[File@ExpandFileName["file"]]` since you are remotely executing a command try expanding *"~"* for whatever *"/host/user/full-path-to-file"*; it seems that `FileExistQ` does not read all **$LocalVariables** of the remote host. Also something like `TableForm[ ReadList["!ls -la ", String], TableSpacing -> {4, 4}, TableAlignments -> Left, TableHeadings -> {Automatic, None}] // TraditionalForm` could work.  This could also work `remoteFileExistQ[file_String] := ExpandFileName[First@ReadList["!ls -a -1 | grep " ~~ file, String]]` in a non-linux remote host using `dir`.

Comment: Why not just write your helper functions into a package, put that on the remote, and load that...? Seems a lot easier than managing all this state yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have some functions defined locally that are not defined on the remote machine. When you remote evaluate your expression, which includes these functions, the remote evaluation doesn't work properly. So, you want your remote evaluation function to transfer all of the necessary local functions to the remote machine, and then evaluate your expression.

The good news is that this is exactly what [`CloudEvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudEvaluate) does, although the remote machine in this case is the WolframCloud and not your remote machine. However, the machinery created to enable [`CloudEvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudEvaluate) to work is already present in Wolfram [`Language`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Language). The function that does the heavy lifting for [`CloudEvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudEvaluate) is `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition ``. A very simple version using this function would be:

```
SetAttributes[compressWithDefinitions, HoldFirst];
compressWithDefinitions[expr_] := With[
    {def = Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[expr]},

    Compress @ Unevaluated[
        Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[] = def;
        expr
    ]
]
```

The compressed string created by this function first loads all necessary definitions needed to evaluate expr, and then evaluates expr.

I will simulate your remote usage by using [`LocalSubmit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalSubmit), which sends an evaluation to a separate kernel. Here is a function only defined in the local kernel:

```
g[x_] := x^2
```

Here are two compress strings that return the downvalues of `g` when uncompressed:

```
str1 = Compress @ Unevaluated[DownValues[g]];
str2 = compressWithDefinitions @ DownValues[g];
```

Now, if we use [`LocalSubmit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalSubmit) with `str1` we find that, as expected, the remote kernel has no downvalues for `g`:

```
Clear[dv];
With[{s = str1},
    LocalSubmit[
        Uncompress[s],
        HandlerFunctions-><|"TaskFinished"->((dv=#EvaluationResult)&)|>,
        HandlerFunctionsKeys->"EvaluationResult"
    ]
];
Pause[1];
dv
```

> {}

On the other hand, when using `str2`, the local kernel does have the transferred downvalues for `g`:

```
Clear[dv];
With[{s = str2},
    LocalSubmit[
        Uncompress[s],
        HandlerFunctions-><|"TaskFinished"->((dv=#EvaluationResult)&)|>,
        HandlerFunctionsKeys->"EvaluationResult"
    ]
];
Pause[1];
dv
```

> {HoldPattern[g[x_]] :> x^2}

So, I think you should be able to use `compressWithDefinitions` to achieve your goals.

Note that there are some additional subtleties that can arise if you try to use package functions, where you need to make sure that the compressed string includes contexts when necessary.

Comment: This worked on first try. Can't thank you enough (being able to use Wolfram on my remote machines from a Wolfram Desktop instance is an amazing superpower for stitching utility scripts together).